# Ecto - how to get records by ids in exact order

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a list of record ids - `[9, 1, 4, 3]`.

I want to retrieve records from postgresql and want them be ordered as in this ids list. But when I make a query, records are returned in arbitrary order:

```
Ecto.Query.from(r in Record, where: r.id in [9, 1, 4, 3]) 
  |> Repo.all()
  |> Enum.map(&Map.get(&1, :id)) # => [4, 9, 1, 3]
```

How could I retrieve records with the same order?

Comment: If you want to do it on a database level then I dont have a better idea but to use `case` in the `order by` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any easy way to do this in the database, but here's a way to do this in Elixir:

```
ids = [123, 4, 1, 3, 2, 456]
posts = from(p in Post, where: p.id in ^ids, select: {p.id, p}) |> Repo.all |> Map.new
posts = for id <- ids, posts[id], do: posts[id]
posts |> Enum.map(&(&1.id)) |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 3, 2]
```

First, we build a map of `id => post`. Then, for each id in `ids`, we get the corresponding Post, if it was found. In my app, there was no Post with id 123 or 456, so they were ignored in `for`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the PostgreSQL's [`array_position` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) and Ecto's [fragment function](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-fragments). In your case, it would look like:

```
Ecto.Query.from(r in Record, where: r.id in [9, 1, 4, 3])
|> Ecto.Query.order_by([r], fragment("array_position(?, ?)", [9, 1, 4, 3], r.id) 
|> Repo.all()
```

I would avoid processing data outside of the database engine. It shouldn't matter in this simple example. However, it might impact performance for bigger data sets or more complex data structures because first, you have to load the results into the memory and then perform operations on them to change the order.

Comment: `idx` function also works - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/intarray.html#id-1.11.7.28.6 but this requires `CREATE EXTENSION intarray;`

Comment: This answer doesn't work when I try to use `^array`

Comment: Not sure where you want to use that array. Maybe should be `array` instead - hard to guess without seeing the code.

Comment: this should be marked as the accepted answer since it is done at database level which is the original question